# How to deal with forgotten passwords in passport with expressjs, postgresql

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, knex.js

I have seen a number of tutorials showing how to allow users to reset forgotten password with Node and mongoose and passportJS.

However, I am using Postgresql/Knex for storing data. I have googled, searched this and other sites, but not found anything. Can anyone point me to a helpful resource?

To clarify, I am looking to solve the problem for users of the application who have forgotten their passwords and can no longer log in to their accounts.

Comment: Have you lost your database connection's password or are you talking about how to make "forgot password" functionality for your application logic so that users of your system may request link to get set new password for themselves?

Comment: Mikael, the second one. I need to solve this problem for my application's users. Clarified the question above.